# Autowiring RestTemplate causes "argument type mismatch" when including Eureka

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

After adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to my dependencies I get the following exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [example.nagios.notificationmanager.core.nagiosapi.NagiosAPIService]: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:267)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 26 more
```

So it fails to create the service with the following constructor

```
@Autowired
public NagiosAPIService(@Value("${nagios.state.uri}") String nagiosStateUri,
    @Qualifier("systemAuthorized") RestTemplate restTemplate, NagiosCheckService nagiosCheckService) {

    this.nagiosStateUri = nagiosStateUri;
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    this.nagiosCheckService = nagiosCheckService;
}
```

I removed one parameter after the other, and it's the RestTemplate which causes the error.

Without spring-cloud-starter-eureka in my dependencies everything works fine. 
Could anybody tell me why eureka causes this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's just that there is some (optional, but active by default if you use that starter) autoconfiguration to monitor rest template usage for metrics. You can probably still autowire a `RestOperations`, or set `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true` to get it to work as is.

Comment: Is there a issue logged for this? Just hit the same thing using spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery:1.0.0.M6

Comment: There have been issues logged. In latest snapshots you should find that `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true` by default, so it wouldn't arise.